# What does "Propagation.NEVER executes non-transactionally" mean in Spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

In the code below, the save operation in `createDevice` method inside `DeviceService` class will not be executed inside a *transaction*. What does it mean that this operation is not executed inside a *transaction*?

Is it possible to execute an operation on the database without a *transaction*?

```
package controller;

import model.Device;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import service.DeviceService;

@RestController
public class DeviceController {

    @Autowired
    private DeviceService deviceService;

    @PostMapping("/devices")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createDevice(@RequestBody Device device) {
        deviceService.createDevice(device);
    }
}
```

--

```
package service;

import model.Device;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import repository.DeviceRepository;

@Service
public class DeviceService {

    @Autowired
    private DeviceRepository deviceRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
    public void createDevice(Device device) {
        deviceRepository.save(device);
    }
}
```

--

```
package repository;

import model.Device;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
public interface DeviceRepository extends JpaRepository<Device, Integer> {
}
```

--

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Device {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
}
```

---

### EDIT

I'm using MySQL database. The Operation gets executed successfully.

- Any details on how this gets executed without a *transaction*?
- What is being done behind the scene?
- What is the difference between executing an operation inside a
  *transaction* and without a *transaction*?

Comment: there should be an exception thrown if there's an active transaction. i've never tried messing with this, i would expect the interceptor checks for the transaction on the way in, if there are dao calls within the service that do their own transactions I would be surprised if those would get an exception thrown for them. looks like you have most of the code, what happens when you try it? and no, you can't have non-transactional sql/dml, but spring will start transactions for you (for individual db operations) if you don't specify them.

Comment: @NathanHughes I'm using MySQL. The operation got executed successfully.